# jquery preloader for div content only

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a WebSite and i want to show a preloader before the page is loaded and ready to display on the screen.

I did found a lot of plugins to do that, but they only works when it's for the whole WebSite. I want to do that only when i load a content inside a specific ID Div. The problem i have is because the content of this div is called based on a menu click and the preloader doesn't work.

This is my HTML for the page:

```
<body>
<div class="head">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="service">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="ip-container" class="ip-container">
    <!--some other codes in here -->

    <div id="content"><!-- content ajax -->

    </div><!-- /content ajax -->

</div><!-- /container -->
</body>
```

I want to show the preloader only when the user click on the menu and the #content div is loaded with it's content.

And this is the Jquery i'm using to call the content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#content').load('content/home.php');
    $('.head').on( 'click', 'li a', function() {

        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php'); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You are basically looking for something like a "loading, please wait..." type dialog display that disappears when the content is loaded?

Comment: Yes, or a gif, something like this. But the problem is, i can't make it happen when i click a menu and the content div loads a page into this div. For example: If i click about, the "please wait" will show up until the #content div loads the content from the "content/about.php", same goes for all the other menus. I already made something like this work, but only when i first load the website, after that, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) offer a success event:

```
$('.loader').show(); // Show the loader here
                     // $('#content').prepend('<div class="loader"...
$('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php', function() {
    alert('Loading complete!');
    $('.loader').hide(); // And hide it
});
```

The goal for you is to create loader div in proper element :)

---

The loader fitting to the size of div:

```js
setTimeout( function() { $('.loader').show(); }, 1000 );
setTimeout( function() { $('.loader').hide(); }, 4000 );
```

```css
#content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative; /* important */
}

.loader {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) url(http://googl-url-shortener.googlecode.com/files/spin_24x24_loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"><div class="loader"></div></div>
```

Comment: Ok, i think i'm almost there. the alert box is working, but the loading gif is not. I did tried to wirte something inside the .load div, but i don't have that either. this is my script.js file http://pastebin.com/0PMFDmhs is it right? (i think it is)

Comment: No, it isn't. Without editing html (just add css `.loader` rule) you have to edit js to [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/06svs96L/)

Comment: but i'm using the css and the div .loader in the html, just like you said before. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: OK, but when you reload the content you lost the loader so you must prepend it before every 'load'. And remove this setTimeout's.

Comment: oh.. i'm so frustrated, i just can't make it work. I spent the night reading about prepend and all those stuffs, but i can't make it happen. Even in fiddle it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/8momL1jk/

Answer (score 3):

```js
setTimeout( function() { $('.loader').show(); }, 1000 );
setTimeout( function() { $('.loader').hide(); }, 4000 );
```

```css
#content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative; /* important */
}

.loader {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) url(https://gelinavillage.gr/images/layout/preloader.gif) center center no-repeat;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"><div class="loader"></div></div>
```